# Manage srce files of the big project

Tags: git, github

We have 2 repositories in the github

a) *Project_all*  <- contains all project files ( too big one)

b) *Project_sr*c <- contains only poject sources

*) Project_all contains folder Project_src. This Project_src folder from Project_all should be sync with Project_src repo.

Usually we work on Project_src files and activly do merge&commit. We usually dont touch the files in Project_all folder.
To make merge&commit easy we create Project_src, which only contains the source files from Project_all folder.

My question is there option to make github automatically synchronize Project_all/Project_src folder with Project_src repo?

If no, than do you have any ideas how easily manage this?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask whose idea was it to use separate repos?  And what is inside the `Project_all` repo besides source files which is making it so large?

Comment: Project_all contains files generated by the tool, it is FPGA project so using source files it generates tons of other files with big sizes.

Comment: My advice is to avoid versioning large files in Git, and if they are binary then don't do it at all.

Comment: Yeah, agree. No they are not binary, but we need to keep all project in git to be able to share between different users, OS and project version. Thus asking community for opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> is there option to make github automatically synchronize Project_all/Project_src folder with Project_src repo?

It is best if Project_all can add and reference Project_src as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**:

```
git submodule add -b master /url/Project_src Project_src
```

That way, every time you want to sync/update your submodule, a simple git submodule update --remote will be enough to fetch the latest from the master branch submodule. Add, commit and push from the main repo.